# UiPath: Collection.contains("string") doesn't appear to be returning Boolean as expected

Tags: uipath

First I use a "Get processes" activity which assigns its result to a variable called currentProcessesCollection which is of type Collection

Next I want to check this condition in and If activity currentProcessesCollection.Contains("OUTLOOK")

I'm getting 'string' cannot be converted to type System.Diagnostics.Process'

I'm kind of flummoxed by this and wondering if anyone knows some other way to do this. I was kind of hoping that writing out the problem would help, it didn't. Thanks for any help in advance. I need to find out if outlook is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly said, `currentProcessCollection` contains a collection of [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.7.2) objects. As such, `Contains` requires another Process object in order to compare them, when you provided the string object "OUTLOOK.EXE".

If you want to search whether at least one process by name exists, just assign the following to a boolean variable (just replace Scan with any process name):

```
processCollection.Where(Function(x) x.ProcessName = "Scan").Count > 0
```